# RDLC Tablix with common and different fields detail

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, report, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I’m using a RDLC for generating reports and I need to print a tablix with product details, the problem is each detail has different fields according to the product type and a basic layout; this is a simplified example of the database tables and printed tables:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umuMD.jpg)

I’ve tried to use rectangles as containers in a list and show/hide according to the type of product but they don’t allow resizing to the content.

Is it subreport a solution?  Should I create one subreport per product type?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to make it work for a while, I've discovered that using a textbox at the bottom of the rectangle allowed the rectangle to resize automatically.